# inline javascript function call - missing ] after element list

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, inline

I have a code:

```
var data = $('<span onclick="someFunction(' + element + ');"><a href="#">Element information</a></span>');
```

where element is a object.

Also, I have a function defined:

```
someFunction: function(element) {
   console.log(element);
   .... // some code
}
```

But when span element tries to call that function, I get error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list 
someFunction([object Object]);
```

When I debug it in `Firebug`, I see

```
<span onclick="someFunction([object Object]);">
   <a href="#">Element information</a>
</span>
```

How can I normally call that function with concrete element as an argument?

Comment: what type of object is element?

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to pass the element as it is converted to string in your concatenation. When an object is converted to string it outputs: [Object object]. This is what you are seeing in your debug.

My suggestion:
You may add the element as data to the span like:

> $('span).data('element', element);

And in someFunction retrieve it like:

> var element = $(this).data('element');

Another option is to bind to click in Javascript at the place where your element is initialized. Like this

```
function anotherFunction() {
  var element = {};

  // Initialize element
  ...

  // I have already got the element initialized, now I can bind the click
  $('span').click(function() {
    // For your debug and validation
    console.log(JSON.stringify(element));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to build some DOM elements with jQuery, you should do this:

```
// Wrong: $('<span onclick="someFunction(' + element + ');"><a href="#">Element information</a></span>');
// Right: build up the element step by step
var data = $('<span/>')
           .append(
               // build up the child <a> element here
               $('<a href="#"/>')
               .text("Element information")
               //.attr('href',"#") Don't really need this
           )
           .click(
               // Here is a real inline function
               function(){
                   someFunction(element);
               }
           );
```

Note: `.click` in jQuery can be used to assign an event handler for the Click event.

---

In your original code, you are trying to concatenate a string with an object, which will result in applying `toString` to that object, converting it to a string:

```
console.log((new Object()).toString()); // [object Object]
console.log("blah" + (new Object())); // blah[object Object]
```

In your code, it seems that your object is in fact a jQuery object, but it won't make any differences.

So the resulting "code" used to form `onclick` is *invalid*:

```
someFunction([object Object]);
```

`[` and `]` is used to construct an Array in JavaScript, like `[1, 2]` is an Array with two elements. However `[object Object]` is an invalid JavaScript syntax so you get the error.

Anyway, this is not a correct way to build up DOM element with events, even with jQuery. The above shown the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

`var data = $('<span onclick="someFunction(' + JSON.stringify(element) + ');"><a href="#">Element information</a></span>');`

The function:

`someFunction: function(element) {
   console.log(element);
   .... // some code
}`

Should return a JSON Object when called.